# Restoring a MSDE database to SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, msde

I am having a hard time trying to get a SQL Server 7.00.1094 backup to restore to a 9.00.1399 (MSDE to 2005) I was told that this will work. However I have done some research and all signs point to detaching and then attaching to the 2005 instance. The software provider specifically said I have to do a backup and restore, not a detach and attach. What is a good way around this? I am unable to upgrade the current instance to 2005 from 7.0.

I am able to add a new database to the 2005 instance, and restore other databases from the 7.0 instance by overwriting the new database I create, I only get this error when trying to restore the master database.

I guess the main question is, how do I successfully restore the system databases from 7.0 (7.00.1094) to 2005 (9.00.1399).

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: The backup of the system database on the device C:\test db run\mvdbtest cannot be restored because it was created by a different version of the server (7.00.1094) than this server (9.00.1399). (Microsoft.SqlServer.Express.Smo)

Comment: Voting to migrate to dba.

Comment: Can you find a 2000 instance somewhere, and restore to that first?

Comment: (As an aside, 7.x is SQL Server 7.0, not SQL Server 2000, which would have a version number of 8.x.)

Comment: Aaron, I could if I had another xp or 2000 machine to load msde on, as it isnt compatible with 7, or 2008r2. That will be my last resort if I am unable to get it converted.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - you should be able to install a new named instance of SQL Server 2000 on your machine, no matter what other instances / versions already exist. I haven't tried 7.0 and 2000 side by side, but even in the case where that is a problem, now that you have the backup you need from the 7.0 instance, you could just blow that instance away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One workaround would be to [download the 2000 version of MSDE](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22661), restore your database to that instance, then take a backup from 2000, and restore *that* backup to 2005. This is the same approach you have to take today in order to get a database from 2000 to 2012.

Comment: I will give this a shot.  Thank you Aaron, I will let you know what happens.

Comment: Aaron, turns out I dont need to move the master db, the other db's that are proprietary to the software we are using are the only ones that need moving. And 2005 and 2008 r2 accept them. I will make this as the correct answer because, if I was truely needing to move the master, this is the correct way.  Thank you very much.